# Excel values not updating

Tags: excel, vba

I've made a function in VBA for excel that counts the number of cells of a certain color in a range, based on a different cell. This works fine first running the function, however when changing the color of one of the cells in the range to or from the color being counted, the value doesn't update. How do I get it so the function continuously updates whenever I change the color? Workbook calulations are set to automatic.

```
Function CountColor(rSumRange As Range)

Dim rCell As Range
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim vResult

iCol = Range("P1").Interior.ColorIndex
For Each rCell In rSumRange
    If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iCol Then
         vResult = vResult + 1
    End If
    Next rCell

CountColor = vResult
End Function
```

Comment: Do you mean - how do i get the function to run whenever any cell in the range changes?

Comment: That would be exactly what I mean!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing color doesn't trigger the `Worksheet_Change()` and doesn't trigger any `Application.Calculate`.

If your workbook doesn't have too many formulas, you can try this *bulky* solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

Comment: This is (currently) the only formula I have, but it's used ~20 times. I added this into the code, but still whenever I change the color the values still aren't updating.

Edit: Disregard this - I'm fairly stupid sometimes.

Comment: That won't work: you need to make the function Volatile. Then if you also want the function to recalculate when the only thing you do is change color you also need to use Max;s selection change macro. But beware: both these actions will significantly slow down recalculation

Answer (score 1):

It will come at the cost of some performance, but you can add "Application.Volatile" inside the code which will make it so that whenever there is a change in the worksheet, it's recalculated.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213653(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: This worked great for whenever I change something in the worksheet, but sadly changing color doesn't set off the Worksheet_Change() thing. Is there any way I could make changing the color do that?

Comment: Ah, your right it doesn't seem to work in this case. Best thing I can think of, if you really want it auto calculated, is to create a worksheet selection changed event that will replace the = in the formula with a =, setting off the recalculation.