# How to continually run function to count yellow cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I've a function in Excel that adds up how many yellow cells there are in the row.

```
 Function CountColorIf(rArea As Range) As Long

    Dim rAreaCell As Range
    Dim lCounter As Long

    For Each rAreaCell In rArea

        If rAreaCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then

            lCounter = lCounter + 1

        End If

    Next rAreaCell

    CountColorIf = lCounter
End Function
```

The code works, however not immediately. For instance say I make two of the cells yellow, I then have to click back into the cell in which this function is placed and press enter for the correct number to appear.

How can I make it run any time the worksheet is changed?

I did find something about Worksheet.event (something like that) but from my understanding that only works with a sub and not a function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel values not updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389065/excel-values-not-updating)

Comment: why not just count based on the conditions that cause the yellow and skip the interior color counting?

Answer (score 1):

You can mark your function as `Volatile` so it gets re-calced every time there is a change. This can be very CPU intensive though because even entering a number will cause it to run.

```
Application.Volatile (True)
```

Comment: This still won't react to a simple colour change, although the function will at least recalculate when something else causes the workbook to recalculate. Bottom line: colour should be used to illuminate data, not as data.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: THIS WILL NOT WORK FOR YOU

Why: The worksheet_change event is not triggered by changing a cell's interior color. I am sorry for the false hope. I will leave the answer up to dismiss your doubts about the Worksheet Change event, but it is not applicable for your situation.

---

Other than Application.Volatile would be the Worksheet_Change event. It will launch whenever there is a change in the worksheet. I turn some stuff off to to it so it takes less resources if your spreadsheet is big.

In order to work it needs to be pasted in your worksheet's code (not a module).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Dim rng as Range

    Application.enableevents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Cells) Is Nothing Then
        set rng = ActiveCell.Entirerow
        msgbox "There are " & CountColorIf(rng) & " yellow cells in this row!"
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.enableevents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic                    
End Sub
```

Comment: You are right that the worksheet_change is a sub, but the sub itself can call your function! In this case I called it as part of a message to the user.