# Excel no longer calculates my fields

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a simple VBA function to look up a value by key in a long table of key/value pairs. It then returns that value as a Double:

```
Public Function GetValue(sheet As String, key As String) As Double
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim K As Range
    GetValue = 0
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet)
    If WS Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    Set K = FindKeyAnywhere(WS, key)
    If K Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    GetValue = WS.Cells(K.Row, 5).Value
End Function
```

I have about 60 of these formulas in a summary sheet:

```
=GetValue("Data", B$41)
```

Where "Data" is the name of the page with key/values, and B$41 is a key. Everything was working perfectly, then...

I fat-fingered the VBA, changing the = 0 to = o and calced. Now every cell on the summary still said `#VALUE`. When I realized what happened, I fixed the error and recalced. However, every cell on the summary still said `#VALUE`.

If I click in the cell and hit return, it updated fine.

I checked, autocalculate *is* turned on. I also clicked calc sheet several times. Nothing.

So I went to every single cell and hit return, so they were all updated. Now they don't say `#VALUE`, but they still don't update when I change data on the data page.

Is there anything special I'm missing? It seems like Excel is "stuck" thinking the calculation isn't valid.

**UPDATE:**

Using a named range does not work well, because it has to be typed into every formula. Consider...

```
        KEY1                KEY2                 ANOTHERKEY
Data1 =GetValue(A$1,B$1)
Data2
```

When the user CnPs or drag-fills that formula, it will get the key and sheet automatically. If we use a range name instead, they would have to type in the name in every single cell, and there's hundreds.

Is there a way to take a string and return the named range? Like `=Range(A1)`

Comment: Where is `FindKeyAnywhere()` defined?

Comment: This sounds trite, but please try shutting down and restarting. Could be a memory issue. It's worked for me before in cases like this.

Comment: Why would the formulas recalculate when you change things on the data page? `=GetValue("Data", B$41)` doesn't have anything on the data page as a precedent cell. Why would the Excel calculation engine recalculate a formula in such a case? Perhaps you need to include `Application.Volatile` in the definition of the function. Another idea would be to have `Worksheet_Change` in the "Data" sheet trigger a calculation. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7389207/4996248) answer.

Comment: I agree with @JohnColeman - Adding `Application.Volatile` might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As John Coleman says: Excel does not know it needs to recalculate when something on the Data sheet changes because the precedents of your UDF do not include the range od information on the Data sheet.

You need to:

- Either Make the function Volatile - but this has bad recalculation
  consequences.
- Or pass the range on the Data sheet that contains the    information
  instead of passing a string. This is the best solution.

Comment: This is probably the answer, and you are surely right that `Application.Volatile` has drawbacks. I am still puzzled as to why OP thinks that it worked in the past (which is why I hesitated in posting it as an outright answer).

Comment: @JohnColeman - it was working, I could see the numbers changing when I ran the SQL that populated the sheet. And they all changed to #VALUE when I made the typo. I wasn't imagining that one!

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - What would be the best way to pass the range in a format that the user can easily enter? The advantage to using this function is that they can type the key into a cell and select it as the input (as in the example). It's easy enough to type "Data1" into a cell and link to it, what would be the corresponding solution using a range?

Comment: @Maury: probably the best solution is to format the Data range as a Table and pass the name of the table as a range: or if you don't like Tables use a Named Range.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - if I go the named-range route, how would the user type that in? Range(thename)? If so, passing in Worksheets(thename) also work? That might be the best, if that works.

Comment: =GetValue(NameofNamedRange,key) or GetValue(NameOfTable,key)

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - no that is a literal, I want the user to be able to type the name as a string into a cell. That way all the formulas are simply =GV(cellwithnameofrange, cellwithnameofkey) and they can copy the formula across arrays and such

Comment: Not sure I understand: its not a string constant its a defined name - no quotes

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update I think you are looking for INDIRECT, which can convert a string to a range.

But there are major downsides to INDIRECT: its volatile, single-threaded and behaves badly when the string the user gives it does not exist.

IMHO this is not a good direction to go: I would recommend you consider a redesign of your data/algorithms.

Comment: Ahhh. So perhaps Application.Volatile is the way to go, along with some careful measurements of the performance.

Comment: Both Application.Volatile and INDIRECT suffer from the same problem: they are trying to fight the way Excel works. Either method may work for you in particular circumstances but for me they are very much the last resort - using them to try to make things easier for users is just asking for trouble. Why cant you work with a table that has 2 keys and a value instead of lots of key value pair tables?